# ANDROID: Application crashes when starting activity after HTTP Request

Tags: android, android-activity, crash, httprequest

I have a problem to solve really fast :)
I have this code:

loginBtn.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            HttpRequest hr = new HttpRequest();
            String response = hr.LoginRequest(emailText.getText().toString(), pwdText.getText().toString());
            res.setText(response);
            res.setVisibility(0);

            if(response.equals("pr_code_0101")) {
                Login.this.startActivity(bcard_intent);
            }
        }
    });
```

The startActivity fails and my application crashes, I got what's the problem: It is the HttpRequest with the LoginRequest that is a custom class created by me, if I remove those 2 lines of code the activity starts...

The code of Http

```
public String LoginRequest(String email, String password)
{
    List<NameValuePair> nvp = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
    nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
    nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("hash_app", hash_code));

    return Set("******/loginrequest.php", nvp);
}

public String Set(String url,List<NameValuePair> list)
{
     StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
     HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
     HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

     try {
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(list));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream content = entity.getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
           builder.append(line);
        } 

        reader.close();
        content.close();

     }
     catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
         return e.toString();
     }
     catch (IOException e) {
         return e.toString();
    }

     return builder.toString();
}
```

How can I solve my problem??

Here the logcat:

```
 01-20 11:25:42.824: E/AndroidRuntime(274): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{name.printernet.app/name.printernet.app.BCard}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

Comment: what does the logcat say?

Comment: where u have initialize  `bcard_intent` intent and make sure u have declared second activity in androidmanifest.xml

Comment: I've done it... In the manifest there is the class declared. About the logcat here it is: 01-20 11:25:42.824: E/AndroidRuntime(274): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{name.printernet.app/name.printernet.app.BCard}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class <unknown>

Answer (score 0):

before putting your HTTP requiest first you have you check using connectivity manager whether you are connected with either

wifi

or

Mobile data to check this 1st add the following permission in the manifestfile

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

then in your class check that availability

```
    ConnectivityManager conMan = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

//mobile
State mobile = conMan.getNetworkInfo(0).getState();

//wifi
State wifi = conMan.getNetworkInfo(1).getState();
```

and then use it like that:

```
if (mobile == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED || mobile == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING) {
    //mobile
} else if (wifi == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED || wifi == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING) {
    //wifi
}
```

after that send send HTTP requst 
because HTTP request have a critera that it should have a  driver like wifi or mobile netwrok to take him to the out side world with your information hope this will help you

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply, but the problem is the startActivity that isnt working, not the http request... The real problem is that after I execute the HttpRequest that work well, the startActivity doesnt work

Comment: then paste your log cat in your question also to figure out the problem